# mySQL stored procedure to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures, export

I created a stored procedure that generates a new table in the database consisting of many parts of other tables.

The thing is that the table generated is not created. I want to send the table generated, let's say to a local location but in JSON format.

Here is the procedure v1 I created.

```
USE DataBase;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ActaReuniones()
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meeting(
        idActaReunion INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        fecha_registro DATE,
        clientid INT,
        idgestor INT,
        Nombre_Cliente VARCHAR(255),
        Gestor VARCHAR(255),
        Perfil VARCHAR(255),
        TipoCliente VARCHAR(255),
        NombreCiudad VARCHAR(255),
        NombreDepartamento VARCHAR(255)
    )  ENGINE=INNODB;

    INSERT INTO meeting (
        idActaReunion,
        fecha_registro,
        clientid,
        idgestor,
        Nombre_Cliente,
        Gestor,
        Perfil,
        TipoCliente,
        NombreCiudad,
        NombreDepartamento
    )
    SELECT * FROM 
        # A lot of queries and joins from other tables to fill the table created.  
        # It works, believe me.
    WHERE AR.fecha_registro < '2020-11-01';
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

After thinking about this, I do not want to duplicate the database (which is exactly what will happen if I run this procedure), so I want to cut off the sections `CREATE` and `INSERT`, letting with only the `SELECT` section.

This section is what I want to send as a JSON file to a local location. I assume that the data collected in the SELECT section is possible to write in a file without passing through a table created previously. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *This section is what I want to send as a JSON file to a local location.* Select JSON (build it using built-in JSON functions) instead of separate columns, what a problem? But if you want the SP to contain one SELECT statement only then not SP but view will be more suitable, is it?

Comment: Hi.  What I meant is:  The outcome of the procedure is one table.  Is there a way that, this table, instead of sending to the Database, be sent to a JSON file automatically?  I mean, is there a way that I save the outcome of the SP as an object -for instance-, and then this object is sent to a location as a JSON file?

Comment: This is possible. SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE saves query output to the text file on the disk using specified exporting options. If your query produces one row with one column which contains needed JSON then this JSON will be saved to file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue after some research.  My approach was as follows:
As the table the query will go to is already created, but we don't want to duplicate the database, so we send the result of the query to the table (with a WHERE previously established); With this result, the JSON is created and this JSON is sent to the desired location. Then a TRUNCATE is performed on the table (all within the procedure):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ActaReuniones()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO meeting (  #the table is already created in the DB
        idActaReunion,
        fecha_registro,
        clientid,
        idgestor,
        Nombre_Cliente,
        Gestor,
        Perfil,
        TipoCliente,
        NombreCiudad,
        NombreDepartamento  
        WHERE DATE
             # the query
        SELECT JSON_OBJECT
            ('idActareunion', idActaReunion,
             'fechaRegistro', fecha_registro, 
             'clientid', clientid,
             'idGestor', idgestor,
             'NombreCliente', Nombre_Cliente,
             'Gestor', Gestor,
             'Perfil', Perfil,
             'TipoCliente', TipoCliente,
             'NombreCiudad', NombreCiudad,
             'NombreDepartamento', NombreDepartamento
             )
        FROM meeting
        INTO OUTFILE '/location/meeting.json';
        
        TRUNCATE TABLE meeting;
           
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

I call this procedure and it works!  Now, I am trying to figure it out how could I update the json file with new data that it is include in the tables included in the query.  I tried to update this file but it is not possible to re-write a json file that is already created.  Let's see.  Any hint I appreciate it.
Kind regards